# Eclipse Java code formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, indentation, auto-indent

I'm writting a GUI program.

It has several JPanels that conatin other components. It would be really nice if my code would look like this:

```
parent component code
    child component code
        grandchild component code
```

instead of this:

```
parent component code
child component code
grandchild component code
```

It would make the code far more readable. Is(Are) there some character(s) I can put in my code that Java will ignore, but Eclipse would detect it as a part of code that has to have additional indentation?

I know I can do all this manually, but I often set indentation automatically (ctrl+a, ctrl+i). That way I don't have to worry about indentation directly, I can make Eclipse manage it for me. However, that also nullifies any "custom" changes I made myself.

Adding {} does the trick, but it also influences on the way java reads the code, so that doesn't really work.

Maybe there are some plug-ins available for this?
Something that would detect lines like e.g.

```
//{
```

and

```
//}
```

and then indent code that is enclosed in them?

Answer (score 2):

Select a block of text with the proper opening and closing braces, and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will format the selected block of text.

Morevoer, in eclipse you can go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Formatter**. Here you can create a new formatter profile and assign a lot of your custom formatting rules.

Screenshot for easy reference

[image: Eclipse Formatter profile]

Comment: I am not aware of any more formatting customization techniques, may be there might a plugin for it.